# Проблема с капчей при запросе с android устройства

Tags: android, rest, captcha, retrofit

Я пытаюсь получать данные с сайта гибдд, при вводе некоторых данных он просит ввести капчу, в rest клиенте в хроме все проходит без проблем с таким алгоритмом работы:
 1. получение сессии
 2. получение капчи, с указанием сессии как 
 3. запрос, в форм дате вписываю данные капчи и другие

Ответ приходит в нормальном виде. Когда делаю это на устройстве, то ответ приходит такой, как будто капча просрочена или введена неверно. Пробовал разные варианты сохранения куков:
 1. сохраняю из сессии
 2. делаю запрос к сайту с формами и оттуда сохраняю куки
 3. при получении капчи сохраняю куки
Все три варианта неработоспособны. Наверняка есть совсем мелкая проблема, которую я пропускаю, но уже мучаюсь дня четыре, ни до чего не могу дойти

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Была такая проблема, ушла когда включил `CookieManager`

```
public class App extends Application {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
            CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
        }
    }
```

в AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest
    package="com.your.package"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:name="com.your.package.App"
```

Comment: Интересно, а запросы через что делали?

Comment: `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: увы, но этот вариант не срабатывает

Comment: моя проблема была в том, чтобы сессия сохранялась